# What is the name of this poem by Mallarmé in French

Tags: poésie

One should be able to find this poem in the original French here

https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Po%C3%A9sies_(Mallarm%C3%A9,_1914,_8e_%C3%A9d.)

If not then Mallarmé's other works are located here

https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Auteur:St%C3%A9phane_Mallarm%C3%A9

Here is the poem in English whose French original version I need

> Crushed by the overwhelming cloud
> Depth of basalt and lavas
> By even the enslaved echoes
> Of a trumpet without power
>
> What sepulchral shipwreck (you
> Know it, slobbering there, foam)
> Among hulks the supreme one
> Flattened the naked mast too
>
> Or that which, furious mistake
> Of some noble ill-fate
> All the vain abyss spread wide
>
> In the so-white hair’s trailing
> Would have drowned miser-like
> The childish flank of some Siren.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about French language itself but rather about helping to find a resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called "À la nue accablante" and in French:

> À la nue accablante tu
> Basse de basalte et de laves
> À même les échos esclaves
> Par une trompe sans vertu
>
> Quel sépulcral naufrage (tu
> Le sais, écume, mais y baves)
> Suprême une entre les épaves
> Abolit le mât dévêtu
>
> Ou cela que furibond faute
> De quelque perdition haute
> Tout l'abîme vain éployé
>
> Dans le si blanc cheveu qui traîne
> Avarement aura noyé
> Le flanc enfant d'une sirène.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.